# Redux very strange issue cause component to unmount

Tags: reactjs, redux

Imagine an app with two components and a main entry :

```
Components
   App
      Actions.js (import some module actions)
      Reducer.js
      Selectors.js
      Container.jsx

   Module
      Actions.js
      Reducer.js
      Selectors.js
      Container.jsx

Lib
   store.js

main.jsx
```

When I call a Module action from App, the Module reducer update the state. It's basic redux usage and that work perfectly.

Now the module is moved in a separate package (each built with Webpack), with lerna (an NPN link alternative) to bootstrap the module in the app (the module is a dependancy of the app). The module export 3 things (a container, the reducer and the actions). The imported reducer is "linked" to the "instanced" App store. It's like using a basic NPM lib.

```
Packages
   App
   Module
lerna.json
```

But with this a structure, when I call the module action, the reducer cause allways the app unmount. I have double/triple/infinite check with a simple reducer, I dont understand where is the issue. I try with this codes :

**Fail**

```
case types.TEST:
  return {
    ...state,
    test: action.payload,
  };
```

**Fail**

```
case types.TEST:
  return {
    ...state,
  };
```

**Work**

```
case types.TEST:
   return state,
```

Each time I try to update the state, I can't change any value. Very strange issue... An idea ?

Comment: I have open an issue here : https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/2437

Comment: it's a bit confusing explained like this. Could you share how you call your reducer? Some code would help. Plus, why did you move away from the app the reduer/action/etc ?